# having trouble with json data and android

Tags: android, json

I'm stuck with this problem. I'm trying to pull some json data from a mysql database. I currently want to use an AsyncTask to do most of the work in the background and potentially use different php scripts to run different queries return different data (which is why i havent inserted the direct url into the httpost)

Basicially right now, I want to retrieve the data from the database, pass it into a variable and then display that variable in a TextView.

When i run the code, it just displays "No Data" in the TextView so something is not working. My php file works fine! Heres the code: Any help greatly appreciated :)

```
package com.example.test1;



import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class clubpage extends Activity {

TextView test;
String clubphp = "http://10.0.2.2/corkgaa/Nemo.php";
String event = "No Data"; 
String name = "No Data"; 
String price = "No Data"; 


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.clubpage);

    test = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.clubinfo);

    new Dbhandler().execute(clubphp);

    test.setText(name);     

}

public class Dbhandler extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JSONArray jArray; 
        String result = "no response"; 
        InputStream is = null; 
        StringBuilder sb = null;

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        //http post 
        try{ 
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("clubphp"); 
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs)); 
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity(); 
            is = entity.getContent(); 
            }
        catch(Exception e){ 
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString()); 
            }

        //convert response to string 
        try{ 
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8); 
            sb = new StringBuilder(); 
            sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n"); 
            String line="0"; 
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { 
                sb.append(line + "\n");
                } 
            is.close(); 
            result=sb.toString(); 
            }
        catch(Exception e){ 
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString()); 
            }

        //parsing data

        try{ 
            jArray = new JSONArray(result); 
        JSONObject json_data=null; 

        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){ 
            json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i); 
            name=json_data.getString("NAME"); 
            event=json_data.getString("EVENT");
            price=json_data.getString("PRICE");
            }
        }
        catch(JSONException e1){ 

            }
        catch (ParseException e1) { 
            e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        return name;
    }   

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
}
```

}

Log cat:

```
03-04 15:25:35.139: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:35.149: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:35.239: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:35.259: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:35.259: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:35.270: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:35.279: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:35.279: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:35.312: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:35.312: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:35.349: I/ActivityManager(288): START u0 {cmp=com.example.test1/.clubpage} from pid 791
03-04 15:25:35.369: W/WindowManager(288): Failure taking screenshot for (246x410) to layer 21020
03-04 15:25:35.389: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:35.419: W/Trace(288): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:35.429: W/Trace(288): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:35.438: W/Trace(288): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:35.459: W/Trace(288): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:35.479: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:35.479: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:35.479: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:35.588: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:35.588: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:35.609: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:36.028: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:36.099: I/Choreographer(791): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-04 15:25:36.109: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:36.168: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:36.268: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:36.279: W/Trace(288): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:36.279: W/Trace(288): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:36.289: V/PhoneStatusBar(580): setLightsOn(true)
03-04 15:25:36.299: W/Trace(288): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:36.358: W/Trace(288): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:36.409: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
03-04 15:25:36.409: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:36.421: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:36.439: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:36.439: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:36.439: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:36.729: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:36.729: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:36.773: I/Choreographer(791): Skipped 158 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-04 15:25:36.779: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:36.779: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:37.209: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:37.209: W/Trace(288): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:37.240: I/ActivityManager(288): Displayed com.example.test1/.clubpage: +1s832ms
03-04 15:25:37.269: W/Trace(288): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:37.269: W/Trace(288): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:37.299: W/Trace(288): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:37.309: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:37.331: W/Trace(288): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:37.399: W/Trace(288): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:37.589: I/Choreographer(791): Skipped 48 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-04 15:25:37.649: D/dalvikvm(288): GC_CONCURRENT freed 980K, 35% free 7576K/11552K, paused 9ms+56ms, total 701ms
03-04 15:25:37.859: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:37.859: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:37.911: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:37.911: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:37.919: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:37.949: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:38.214: W/Trace(288): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:38.250: W/Trace(288): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:38.250: W/Trace(288): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:38.309: W/Trace(288): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:38.369: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:38.409: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:38.419: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:38.439: W/Trace(288): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:38.479: W/Trace(288): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:38.519: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:38.530: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:38.530: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:38.549: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:38.549: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:38.549: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:38.549: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:38.629: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:38.629: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:38.690: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:38.699: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:38.699: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:38.719: W/Trace(288): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:38.739: W/Trace(288): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-04 15:25:38.759: W/Trace(791): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add an `onPostExecute()` method to your `Dbhandler` class and set the TextView's text value in that method:

```
public class Dbhandler extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        [...]
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String newName) {
        test.setText(newName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("clubphp");

just replace this line with the following code

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(arg0[0]);

and

implement on post execute as follows

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String resultName) {
       test.setText(resultName);
    }
```

hope it will work 
just post log cat here still if you find any issue

Comment: Thanks for the help but unfortunately its still not returning what i want, still returning "no data" I've posted the log cat up above under my question. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your 10.0.2.2 with your system ip address and add a log that prints the name before returning the name. In doInbackground to know the ip address of your system execute ipconfig  in command prompt